# layzr.js doesn't load the last image

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using [layzr.js](http://callmecavs.github.io/layzr.js/) in my backbone.js project, in order to do a lazy loading image.

Here I put it in my backbone view :

```
render: function(){
    var _item = _.template(ItemTem);
    this.$el.html(_item(this.model.toJSON()));

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var layzr = new Layzrr({
            selector: '[data-layzr]',
            attr: 'data-layzr',
            retinaAttr: 'data-layzr-retina',
            bgAttr: 'data-layzr-bg',
            threshold: 0,
            callback: null
        });
    });
    }
 });
```

Every image works fine except the last image, it is not loaded. I have no idea what's wrong with it or did I do any thing wrong.

I attempted to find an answer to my question with the search engine but i was unable to.

Answer (score 0):

First off remove `$(document).ready(function() {` from your view render method.
You should have DOM ready before view is rendered.

Remove that lazyloader logic altogether form render. And move it to it's parent.

You need to make sure that your view is rendered in DOM before you bind anything to it.

So I would to it this way:

---

```
var yerrView = new YourView();
$('body').append(yerrView.render().el);
var layzr = new Layzrr({
  selector: '[data-layzr]',
  attr: 'data-layzr',
  retinaAttr: 'data-layzr-retina',
  bgAttr: 'data-layzr-bg',
  threshold: 0,
  callback: null
});
```

I would write custom lazy loader for backbone if I were you.